# grayscale css not working in chrome or firefox or fiddle

Tags: css

I am trying to grayscale an `image` and this is the code I am using:

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
 .comment{
  margin-left: 50px;
 }

 img.resize{
     width:40px;
     height: auto;
 }
  
  img {
   filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
   filter: grayscale(1); /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
 }
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-b-128.png" class="img-responsive resize">
```

But its not working. Any ideas why?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zwa9hcf9/3/) I have an example.

Comment: The image in your fiddle is black and white. Here is a fiddle with a color image and it is working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ymqacdo2/1/

Comment: `filter: grey;` removes the color from the image and turns those colors into shades of grey (from white to black), so darker colours (ie. Red, Blue, etc) become darker shades of grey. You're using a black icon so you won't see the effects.

Comment: ah. I thought it just turns all colors grey- whether black or not. I see thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to gray-scale an `image` which is already Black and White, so try to gray-scale a colored image, hover it see the `image` back to colored

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.comment {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
img.resize {
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
}
img {
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}

img:hover {
  filter:0;
  /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" class="img-responsive resize">
```

Comment: dippas was too fast! But, yes, your image is black and white, lol :) It has to be in color to see the effects.